# Can ANDROID_ABIS be specified in my QMake project file (.pro file)

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

When I open a .pro file with QtCreator 4.12.0 (with Qt 5.14.2), it runs QMake with the following arguments:

```
C:\Android_new\QtCreator5_14_2\5.14.2\android\bin\qmake.exe C:\dev\vobs_2019\build\tinyxml\tinyxml-2.6.2\win64\msvc142\tinyxml.pro -spec android-clang "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler" ANDROID_ABIS="armeabi-v7a" && C:/Android_new/android_sdk/ndk-bundle/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make.exe qmake_all
```

You see only "armeabi-v7a" is used by default. If I want to handle more, I have to go to project settings and check the other ABI ("arm64-v8a", "x86"...).

Is there no way to specify the ABI supported by my project in the .pro file itself (I tried to add `ANDROID_ABIS="armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a"` but it had no effect).

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes ?

Comment: Please, see the answer I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can add the line `ANDROID_ABIS = armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a` in the .pro file. This will overwrite the project page choice for the current project (even if this selection is not reflected in the project page dialog), `QtCreator` will build all specified targets (project page choice is ignored for good).

Answer (score 0):

Click on Project in the left pane then choose Build under your Build & Run configuration. In the Build Steps, look for "qmake:". Expand it by clicking on Details and choose the target ABI.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question "Is there no way to specify the ABI supported by my project in the .pro file itself"